# How to configure web map data layer that can accept csv data uploaded by user?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, csv, arcgis-online

I made this map: http://tinyurl.com/a368268 on arcgis online. How do I get the same map but instead you can upload a new csv every time? Instead of having to first add it as data layer on arcgis online and then configure pop ups after doing that. I basically want what I made but be able to upload a new csv with new data but in the same format. The fields I'm using currently are:

ImageName,Latitude,Longitude,PicURL

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found the answer here: http://video.arcgis.com/watch/2066/creating-new-empty-hosted-feature-services

Just watch the video.